# SQL- using multiple condition instead of join and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm kinda new to programming and SQL, just wondering if there's an unwritten rule, reason, or disadvantages about using join/subquery instead of multiple conditions. Something like this:

```
select column
from table1
where table1.A=table2.B and
table2.C=table3.D and
table3.E=table4.F;
```

is it ok to use this in work environment?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Both approaches are appropriate depending on how your data is modeled.

Comment: Your query makes no sense, and would not even compile, because your `FROM` clause only references `table1` and no other tables.  Can you post a functioning query?

Comment: Your have a wrong form clause if you don't want expict join clause

Answer (score 0):

As others have hinted, it is not terribly clear what you are trying to achieve here. What is clear, is you want to work with data in 4 tables, and choose data from table1 based upon data in the other tables.

Therefore you must use JOIN in order to query across multiple tables, for example:

```
USE yourDatabaseName;
select t1.someColumn
    ,t1.someOtherColumn
    ,t2.someColumn
    ,t3.someColumn
    ,t4.someColumn
from table1 t1 JOIN 
table2 t2 ON t1.someIDColumn = t2.someIDColumn JOIN
table3 t3 ON t3.someIDColumn = t2.someIDColumn JOIN
table4 t4 ON t4.someIDColumn = t3.someIDColumn WHERE
t1.targetColumn = t2.targetColumn AND
t2.targetColumn = t3.targetColumn AND
t3.targetColumn = t4.targetColumn;
```

Here, you have multiple fields from multiple tables specified in the `SELECT` clause, and `JOIN` clauses that use specific unique ID fields of some kind to join the tables together.

Note that in the example here, each of the occurrences of `targetColumn` might be different column names - they do not have to be named the same, but they must be the same data type for an explicit equality comparison.

The same goes for the `someIDColumn` column names. For those, you need a column that is present in both tables, to have a comparison (again, the column can be named differently in each table).

Usually, the column names specified after the `ON` portion of a `JOIN` clause will be some sort of unique ID column, (i.e. `userID` or `subscriptionID`) which is shared across tables and intended to be used as a foreign key in exactly these sorts of relational queries.

**Bottom line:**

You cannot simply refer to multiple tables in a query like you did in your example, without joining them together in some way.

Every column specified in the `SELECT` clause must either belong to the table named before the first `JOIN`, or it must belong to one of the tables specified within a `JOIN` clause, in which case you must precede the column name with either the table name or an established alias of the table name, which I used here for each table (`t1`, `t2`... etc.).

Cheers,
-=Cameron